# Convert Array values into Column name for another Array value in PySpark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, databricks

I have the below input table with array values in it. To get the expected output I've tried `array_contains`, but wasn't able to get it.

The array index numbers should exactly match between the two columns

```
Input:
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
|ID             |col_List          |col_ID              |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
|10001          |["T1","T2]        |["100","200"]       |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
|10002          |["T2"]            |["300"]             |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
|10003          |["T1","T2","T3"]  |["150","220","580"  |
+---------------+------------------+--------------------+

Expected output:
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+
|ID             |T1      |T2      |T3      |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+
|10001          |100     |200     |null    |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+
|10002          |null    |300     |null    |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+
|10003          |150     |220     |580     |
+---------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `arrays_zip` to create a struct using the values of the arrays. So, first elements from both the arrays will be used to create a struct, then second elements will be used to create another struct, and so on. Explode the resulting array of structs to get individual rows for each values. We can then pivot the `col_list` and use `col_id` values.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('col_struct_arr', func.arrays_zip('col_list', 'col_id')). \
    withColumn('col_struct', func.explode('col_struct_arr')). \
    select('id', func.col('col_struct.*')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('col_list'). \
    agg(func.first('col_id')). \
    show()

# +-----+----+---+----+
# |   id|  t1| t2|  t3|
# +-----+----+---+----+
# |10002|null|300|null|
# |10001| 100|200|null|
# |10003| 150|220| 580|
# +-----+----+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

After `arrays_zip`, you can do [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) explosion. Then, [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html) looks necessary.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(10001, ["T1","T2"], ["100","200"]),
     (10002, ["T2"], ["300"]),
     (10003, ["T1","T2","T3"], ["150","220","580"])],
    ['ID', 'col_List', 'col_ID'])
```

Script:

```py
df = df.selectExpr("ID", "inline(arrays_zip(col_List, col_ID))")
df = df.groupBy('ID').pivot('col_List').agg(F.first('col_ID'))

df.show()
# +-----+----+---+----+
# |ID   |T1  |T2 |T3  |
# +-----+----+---+----+
# |10001|100 |200|null|
# |10002|null|300|null|
# |10003|150 |220|580 |
# +-----+----+---+----+
```